# Phonegap errorUrl not working

Tags: phonegap-build

I created a barebone app from  phonegap build in which I encoded a site in the content src tag of config.xml and it works smoothly, but whenever network is down it shows the actual error page where the URL is shown, i didnt like it, so added errorUrl as said in   http://www.raymondcamden.com/2013/02/19/Some-examples-of-Android-PhoneGap-Config-Settings

But I always get Application Error - Network error (file:///assests/www/myErrorPage.html)

You can find the screenshot of it at the bottom of that page as I posted it there.

I tried placing the errorpage in several location, like creating assets/www and even in the main folder along with config.xml but still the same error.

My directory structure is config.xml, res (folder containing icons),myErrorPage.html

Can someone help me in this?

Answer (score 0):

@chandru,
it is likely you have some assets online (on the network). Move those assets to the mobile device.
For example, if you have this:
`<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>`
Change it to this:
`<script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>`

Here are some other tips.
[Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md)